# Display Out of Stock Products in the End on Category Pages - Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, stock, out-of-stock

I want to display all out of stock products in end on category pages, I have tested few solution which is mentioned on Magento stack exchange, But no one is working for me.  Anybody can help me regarding how to i can sort out products on base of quantity/stock ? I want to show first Instock product on all category pages, and all out of stock product should be display in end on category pages. I am using Magento 2.4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on a 2.4.0 store

https://github.com/tuyennn/magento2-outofstockatlast

Answer (score 0):

1)First of all you have to create a di.xml and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" type="vendor\module\Block\Product\ProductsList" />
</config>
```

2)Then create a block as follows:

```
<?php
namespace vendor\module\Block\Product;

class ProductsList extends \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList
{

}
```

3)create templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml and copy following code:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
/** @var \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $block */?>
<?php if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())) : ?>
    <?php
    $type = 'widget-product-grid';
    $mode = 'grid';
    $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
    $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();

    $showWishlist = true;
    $showCompare = true;
    $showCart = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
    $description = false;
    ?>
    <div class="block widget block-products-list <?= $mode ?>">
        <?php if ($block->getTitle()) : ?>
            <div class="block-title">
                <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($block->getTitle())) ?></strong>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
        <div class="block-content">
            <?= '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
            <div class="products-<?= $mode ?> <?= $mode ?>">
                <ol class="product-items <?= $type ?>">
                    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
                        <?= ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item">' : '</li><li class="product-item">' ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                       class="product-item-link">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>
                                <?php if ($templateType) : ?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml($_item, $type) ?>
                                <?= $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_item) ?>
                                <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare || $showCart) : ?>
                                    <div class="product-item-inner">
                                        <div class="product-item-actions">
                                            <?php if($showCart) : ?>
                                            
                                            <div class="fieldset">
                                                    <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                                                    <div class="control">
                                                    
                                                    <input type="number"
                                                           name="qty"
                                                           id="<?= 'qty_'.$id ?>"
                                                           value="<?php echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                                                           title="<?php echo __('Qty') ?>"
                                                           class="input-text qty"
                                                           data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                                                           />
                                                    
                                                <div class="actions-primary">
                                                    <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                                        <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_item); ?>
                                                        <?php $id = $_item->getId(); ?>
                                                        <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($postParams['action']) ?>" method="post">
                                                            <input 
                                                                type="hidden"
                                                                name="product"
                                                                value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($postParams['data']['product']) ?>"
                                                                >
                                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                                id="<?= $id.'_qty'?>"
                                                                name="qty"
                                                                value="qty"
                                                                >
                                                            <input 
                                                                type="hidden"
                                                                name="<?= Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>"
                                                                value="<?= $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>"
                                                                >
                                                            <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                            <button type="submit"
                                                                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                    class="action tocart primary">
                                                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </form>
                                                    <?php else : ?>
                                                        <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                                            <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php else : ?>
                                                            <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php if ($showWishlist || $showCompare) : ?>
                                                <div class="actions-secondary" data-role="add-to-links">
                                                    <?php if ($this->helper(\Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::class)->isAllow() && $showWishlist) : ?>
                                                        <a href="#"
                                                           data-post='<?= $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item) ?>' class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Wish List')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')) ?></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl() && $showCompare) : ?>
                                                        <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare::class);?>
                                                        <a href="#" class="action tocompare" data-post='<?= $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item) ?>' title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Compare')) ?>">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')) ?></span>
                                                        </a>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?= ($iterator == count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: then you have to get stock quantity based in product ids and add to this template

Comment: Need to create an extension ? or i just  need to create these files and folders ? Kindly explain me little more. Thanks

Comment: you can try it in existing extension also.just create files and folders

Comment: i am confusing about 3rd point, where i'll create this template ? Please

Comment: path is mentioned after step 3

Answer (score 0):

You can create a before plugin on `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar::setCollection()`

Create `Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!--  out of stock product at end of list -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module::OutofstockEnd" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar.php` add the following:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList;
 
class Toolbar
{
    public function beforeSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        $collection
    ) {
        $collection->setOrder('is_salable', 'desc');
        return [$collection];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working properly, showing empty product list page